# Maxrecursion and Column caused an overflow errors

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am getting a max recursion error with this query.

```
WITH [Days] AS
(   
    SELECT DATENAME(weekday,getdate()) AS NameOfDay
          ,DAY(GETDATE()) AS NumberOfDay
          ,GETDATE() AS curDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(day, -1, curDate)) As NameOfDay
          ,DAY(DATEADD(DAY, -1, curDate)) AS NumberOfDay
          ,DATEADD(DAY, -1, curDate) AS curDate
    FROM [Days]
    WHERE DAY(GETDATE()) - DAY(DATEADD(DAY, -1, curDate)) >= 0
)
SELECT NameOfDay
FROM [Days]  
ORDER BY NumberOfDay
```

and the error is :

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

When I add `option (maxrecursion 0)` to the query, I get this error:

> Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.

I do not know how to resolve these errors. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to get the names of days based on current week.

Comment: @Arpita name of days based on current week? what? I don't understand. How many record do you expect?

Comment: One useful trick for debugging this kind of issue is to add a column that just starts at 1 and counts up. Change the termination condition to limit the count to a reasonable value and examine the results (*). You might want to add columns for the values in your `WHERE` condition to make it easier to see what is going astray.

Comment: @king.code - I mean for today, I want to show Monday,Tuesday and Wednesday in the table. Tomorrow, I want to show Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday.

Comment: So you want to start at today's day-of-the-week and walk back until you get to a Monday (based on `DatePart` `weekday`), then sort it right way around?

Comment: @HABO - Yes. I do not know how else can I achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SET DATEFIRST 7;
GO
WITH [Days] AS
(   
    SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) AS NameOfDay
          ,DAY(GETDATE()) AS NumberOfDay
          ,GETDATE() AS curDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(day, -1, curDate)) As NameOfDay
          ,DAY(DATEADD(DAY, -1, curDate)) AS NumberOfDay
          ,DATEADD(DAY, -1, curDate) AS curDate
    FROM [Days]
    WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, -1, curDate)) >= 2
)
SELECT NameOfDay
FROM [Days]
```

Comment: Is the value of explicitly allowing _unlimited_ recursion the possibility that future weeks might be much longer than seven days? Or just that someone may have altered the default recursion limit?

Comment: @HABO I've just modified the `WHERE` condition. The `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` can be deleted.

Comment: @king.code But if OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) is deleted, "The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion" error will show up again, right?.

Comment: @Arpita nope. Just try it out. The recursion will stop when curDate - 1 is Monday.